# Finite dimensional distributions of brownian motion changed at a random point

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

In the book on Brownian Motion by Yuval Peres, he makes the following claim:

> Suppose that $\{ B(t); \ t \geq 0 \}$ is a Brownian Motion and $U$ is an independent random variable, uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Then the process $\{ \tilde{B} (t); \ t \geq 0 \}$ defined as,
>   $$\tilde{B}(t) = \begin{cases} B(t)  & \mbox{ if $t \neq U$} \\ 0  & \mbox{ if $t = U$} \end{cases}$$
>
> has the same finite-dimensional distributions as a Brownian motion, but is discontinuous if $B(U) \neq 0$, i.e. with probability one, and hence this process is not a Brownian motion.

I'm having difficulty in proving that the finite dimensional joint distribution ( basically the joint distribution of $( \ \tilde{B}(t_1), \ \tilde{B}(t_2), \tilde{B}(t_3), \dots \tilde{B}(t_n) \ )$ ) is the same as the finite dimensional distribution of $B(t)$. Can you please give me some clues.

Comment: Can you show that $B_t$ has the same distribution as $\bar{B}_t$ for fixed $t$?

Comment: For each $t$, $B(t) =\tilde B(t)$ almost surely.

Comment: Yes I understand the $t, \ B(t) = \tilde B(t)$ almost surely, but if random variables are the same a.s, does it imply their joint distributions are the same a.s.  Also how'd you prove discontinuity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since

$$\{B_t \neq \tilde{B}_t\} \subseteq \{U=t\}$$

for any $t \geq 0$ we have

$$\bigcup_{j=1}^n \{B_{t_j} \neq \tilde{B}_{t_j}\} \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^n \{U=t_j\},$$

and so

$$\mathbb{P}(\exists j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}: B_{t_j} \neq \tilde{B}_{t_j}) \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{P}(U=t_j)=0;$$

this implies readily that $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(\tilde{B}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ have the same finite dimensional distribution.

Since $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths, we know that $$\lim_{\substack{s \to U(\omega) \\ s \neq U(\omega)}} \tilde{B}_s(\omega) = \lim_{\substack{s \to U(\omega) \\ s \neq U(\omega)}} B_s(\omega) = B_U(\omega)$$

for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$. This shows that

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\omega; t \mapsto \tilde{B}_t(\omega) \, \, \text{is discontinuous at $t=U(\omega)$}\}) = \mathbb{P}(B_U \neq 0) = 1.$$

In particular, each sample path $t \mapsto \tilde{B}_t(\omega)$ has at least one discontinuity with probability 1.

Comment: @VoB Since $U$ and $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ are independent, we have $$\mathbb{P}(B_U \neq 0) = \int \mathbb{P}(B_u \neq 0) \, d\mathbb{P}_U(u) = \int 1 \, d\mathbb{P}_U(u)=1,$$ where $\mathbb{P}_U$ denotes the distribution of $U$.

Comment: Are these intermediate steps correct? :$\mathbb{P}(B_U \neq 0) = \int \mathbb{P}(B_u \neq 0 | U = u) \, d\mathbb{P}_U(u) = \int \mathbb{P}(B_u \neq 0) \, d\mathbb{P}_U(u).$

Comment: @Error404 Yeah, it's okay.

Comment: Thanks! Also does $\, d\mathbb{P}_U(u) = \mathbb{P}(u = U)$? I am asking this because $\mathbb{P}(B_U \neq 0)= \text{"sum over" [0,1] of} \; \mathbb{P}(B_u \neq 0, u=U) = \text{"sum over" [0,1] of} \; \mathbb{P}(B_u \neq 0| u = U)\mathbb{P}(u=U).$