# Example: $\tilde{B}(t)$ is not a brownian motion clarification

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, brownian-motion

I started reading the book *Brownian motion* by Mörters and Peres where I don't quite understand the following example. For completeness I've provided the definitions for **brownian motion** and **finite dimensional distributions** used in the book.

> **Definition $1.1$**$ . \quad$ A real-valued stochastic process $\{B(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ is called a (linear) Brownian motion with start in $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if the following holds:
>
> $\bullet\hspace{0,2cm} B(0)=x,$
>
> $\bullet\hspace{0,2cm}$the process has **independent increments**, i.e. for all times  $0 \leqslant t_{1} \leqslant t_{2} \leqslant \ldots \leqslant t_{n}$ the increments $B\left(t_{n}\right)-B\left(t_{n-1}\right), B\left(t_{n-1}\right)-B\left(t_{n-2}\right), \ldots, B\left(t_{2}\right)-B\left(t_{1}\right)$ are independent random variables,
>
> $\bullet\hspace{0,2cm}$ for all $t \geqslant 0$ and $h>0,$ the increments $B(t+h)-B(t)$ are normally distributed with expectation zero and variance $h$
>
> $\bullet\hspace{0,2cm}$ almost surely, the function $t \mapsto B(t)$ is continuous.
>
> We say that $\{B(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion if $x=0$.
>
> By the **finite-dimensional distributions** of a stochastic process $\{B(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ we mean the laws of all the finite dimensional random vectors
> $$
> \left(B\left(t_{1}\right), B\left(t_{2}\right), \ldots, B\left(t_{n}\right)\right), \text { for all } 0 \leqslant t_{1} \leqslant t_{2} \leqslant \ldots \leqslant t_{n}
> $$
> To describe these joint laws it suffices to describe the joint law of $B(0)$ and the increments
> $$
> \left(B\left(t_{1}\right)-B(0), B\left(t_{2}\right)-B\left(t_{1}\right), \ldots, B\left(t_{n}\right)-B\left(t_{n-1}\right)\right), \text { for all } 0 \leqslant t_{1} \leqslant t_{2} \leqslant \ldots \leqslant t_{n}
> $$

> **Example 1.2** Suppose that $\{B(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ is a Brownian motion and $U$ is an independent random variable, which is uniformly distributed on [0,1] . Then the process $\{\tilde{B}(t): t \geqslant 0\}$ defined by
> $$
> \tilde{B}(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> B(t) & \text { if } t \neq U \\
> 0 & \text { if } t=U
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> has the same finite-dimensional distributions as a Brownian motion, but is discontinuous if $B(U) \neq 0,$ i.e. with probability one, and hence this process is not a Brownian motion.

Now my questions are

1. Why does $\tilde{B}(t)$ have the same finite-dimensional distributions as a Brownian motion ?
2. Why is $B(U)\neq 1$ with probability one ?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683396/36150) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2635449/36150)

Comment: Totally answers it. Thank you