# Induction step in Lévy's construction of brownian motion: Why is $B(d)$ independent of $(Z_{t}: t \in \mathcal{D} \backslash \mathcal{D}_{n})$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, brownian-motion, independence

I'm currently reading the proof that brownian motion exists in Peter Mörters and Yuval peres's  book *Brownian Motion*. In their construction they use an inductive step in the beginning in which I don't understand a step. For completness I've put all of the proof up to the unclear step in the question. For the exact definition of brownian motion used in the book see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598705/example-tildebt-is-not-a-brownian-motion-clarification).

> We first construct Brownian motion on the interval [0,1] as a random element on the space $\mathbf{C}[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1] .$ The idea is to construct the right joint distribution of Brownian motion step by step on the finite sets
>   $$
> \mathcal{D}_{n}=\left\{\frac{k}{2^{n}}: 0 \leqslant k \leqslant 2^{n}\right\}
> $$
>   of dyadic points. We then interpolate the values on $\mathcal{D}_{n}$ linearly and check that the uniform limit of these continuous functions exists and is a Brownian motion.
>
> To do this let $\mathcal{D}=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{D}_{n}$ and let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space on which a collection $\left\{Z_{t}: t \in \mathcal{D}\right\}$ of independent, standard normally distributed random variables can be defined. Let $B(0):=0$ and $B(1):=Z_{1} .$ For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define the random variables $B(d), d \in \mathcal{D}_{n}$ such that
>
> $\hspace{1cm}(1)$ for all $r<s<t$ in $\mathcal{D}_{n}$ the random variable $B(t)-B(s)$ is normally distributed with mean zero and variance $t-s,$ and is independent of $B(s)-B(r)$
>
> $\hspace{1cm}(2)$ the vectors $(B(d): d \in \mathcal{D}_{n})$ and $(Z_{t}: t \in \mathcal{D} \backslash \mathcal{D}_{n})$ are independent.
>
> Note that we have already done this for $\mathcal{D}_{0}=\{0,1\} .$ Proceeding inductively we may assume that we have succeeded in doing it for some $n-1 .$ We then define $B(d)$ for $d \in \mathcal{D}_{n} \backslash \mathcal{D}_{n-1}$ by
>   $$
> B(d)=\frac{B\left(d-2^{-n}\right)+B\left(d+2^{-n}\right)}{2}+\frac{Z_{d}}{2^{(n+1) / 2}}
> $$
>   Note that the first summand is the linear interpolation of the values of $B$ at the neighbouring points of $d$ in $\mathcal{D}_{n-1} .$ Therefore $B(d)$ is independent of $\left(Z_{t}: t \in \mathcal{D} \backslash \mathcal{D}_{n}\right)$ and the second property is fulfilled.

Now my question is: Why is $B(d)$ independent of $\left(Z_{t}: t \in \mathcal{D} \backslash \mathcal{D}_{n}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can prove by induction on $n$ that if $d\in\mathcal D_n$, then $B(d)$ is a function of $\left(Z_d,d\in\mathcal D_n\right)$. It is true for $n=1$, an if it is true for $n-1$ then take $d\in\mathcal D_n\setminus \mathcal D_{n-1}$ and 
using 
$$
B(d)=\frac{B\left(d-2^{-n}\right)+B\left(d+2^{-n}\right)}{2}+\frac{Z_{d}}{2^{(n+1) / 2}},
$$
we notice that $d-2^{-n}$ and $d+2^{-n}$ belong to $\mathcal D_{n-1}$ (since $d\notin \mathcal D_{n-1}$, $d=(2k-1)2^{-n}$) and by the induction assumption, 
$B\left(d-2^{-n}\right)$ and $B\left(d+2^{-n}\right)$ are functions of $\left(Z_d,d\in\mathcal D_{n-1}\right)$ hence of $\left(Z_d,d\in\mathcal D_n\right)$.

Comment: How do you get $d = (2k-1)2^{-n}$?

Comment: If $d$ was of the form $\ell 2^{-n}$ where $\ell$ is an even number, then we would have $d\in\mathcal D_{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks